# Is $S = \{ (x^T Q_1 x, x^T Q_2 x) \mid \|x\|_2 = 1 \}$ convex?

Tags: matrices, convex-analysis, convex-geometry

I tried to investigate the convexity of set

$$S = \{ (x^T Q_1 x, x^T Q_2 x) \mid \|x\|_2 = 1 \}$$

where $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are arbitrary $n \times n$ symmetric matrices, and $n > 2$. For the sake of intuition, I've plotted the set with a simple code that has the following result:

[image: set S]

It seems that $S$ is a convex set, but I'm looking for a clear mathematical proof.

Comment: you chose PSD $Q_1$ and $Q_2$, right ?

Comment: In the plotted figure $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ are PSD, but I tested symmetric matrices with negative eigenvalues and the result was the same, but about the definition of the set,  I'm sure it's correct and if you chose $n>2$ then it includes borders and interior. @Ahmad Bazzi

Comment: no, matrices $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ apply on  $x$ such that $x$ is on the border of $L_2$ norm ball, also in the code I've chosen random $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$, normalize them and then apply matrices. even in the extreme case that you mentioned, the set $S$ is a single point and it's convex.@Ahmad Bazzi

Comment: Also if you remove the normalization, we still get convexity, no ?

Comment: no, without normalization, I set $n=3$ and the result wasn't convex. @Ahmad Bazzi

Comment: what choice of $Q_1,Q_2$ gave you a non convex result ?

Comment: with normalization, all symmetric matrices $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ have a convex result; but without normalization, it seems that only PSD $Q_1$ and $Q_2$ gave us convex result. @Ahmad Bazzi

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$S = \{(x^TQ_1x, x^TQ_2x) : \ x^Tx = 1\}$ is a convex compact set in $\mathbb{R}^2$ for $n\ge 3$. 
For $n=2$, the statement is not true.
See Theorem 2.1 in [1], or Theorem 14.1 (page 89) in [2].

Also see: Fact 8.14.11 (page 498) in [3].

*Reference*

[1]  L. Brickman, "On the fields of values of a matrix", Proc. Amer. Math. Soc., 12:61–66, 1961.

[2] A. Barvinok, "A Course in Convexity", Graduate Studies in Mathematics, vol. 54, 2002.

[3] D. S. Bernstein, "Matrix Mathematics: Theory, Facts, and Formulas", 2009.